# Changing static variable in application thread has no effect

Tags: multithreading, android

This is my thread:

```
        public void run() {
    Log.d("ConnectionThread","Starting Server Connection");
        try {
            while(isThereActivityRunning()) {
                if(AppLoader.getIsInternetOn() == true)
                {
                    Log.d("ConnectionThread", "Internet is On. Sending Http request");
                    results = sendGetMessage();
                    b.putString("results", results);
                    receiver.send(2, b);
                }
                else
                    Log.d("ConnectionThread","Internet is Off. Sleeping");
                Thread.sleep(timeInterval);
            }
```

I have the `getIsInternetOn()` function which is a static function in my `AppLoader` class (which extends `Application`).

For some reason whenever I change the value of the static boolean variable inside `AppLoader` to `false`, it doesn't seem to affect on the code above.

The weird thing that inside my activity I'm able to change an view the same variable with the same functions:

```
       btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           if (AppLoader.getIsInternetOn())
               AppLoader.setIsInternetOn(false);
           else
               AppLoader.setIsInternetOn(true);
        }

    });
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           if (AppLoader.getIsInternetOn())
               internetStatus.setText("Internet is On");  
           else
               internetStatus.setText("Internet is Off");  
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add `volatile` modifier to your static variable.

**UPD:**

It may happened because of caching the value for performance purposes.

Comment: so what could i do ? and how come it happens only in the thread ??

Comment: Thread takes value of the variable and cache it, to avoid it you can declare your static variable like this: `public static volatile boolean mNameOfVariable;`

Comment: ive tried it and it didnt work. can it be because im calling a function and not the variable directly?

Comment: if you always receives `DEBUG` message with `ConnectionThread` in LogCat, and click that buttons that changes the variable's value, I do not think the problem inside this code you provided.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to declare your boolean variable as `volatile`.